# Platform indication for obtaining data from sensors around the world

Tags: api, iot, sensors

Can anyone suggest me a free plataform or API to retrieve data from sensors (in real time if possible)?
The data type can be about weather, agriculture or similar.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.